# How to prove whether $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}: y>x^2\}$ is open with open set definition

Tags: general-topology, analysis

$S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}: y>x^2)\}$ is intuitively open. But we have to prove a set is open iff
$$\forall (x_0,y_0) \in \mathbb{R^2}, \; \exists \varepsilon >0 \;\; \text{such that} \;\; \mathcal{B_{\varepsilon}}((x_0,y_0)) \subset S$$

We know that by assumption, $y_{0}-x_{0}^2 > 0$. Now, let

$$(z,w) \in \mathcal{B_{\varepsilon}(x_{0},y_{0})}$$ We want to show that $(z,w) \in S$. Moreover, $z-w^2>0$.

$$||(x_0,y_0)-(z,w)|| <\varepsilon$$

Simply,

$$|x_0-z|<\varepsilon, \;\; |y_0-w|<\varepsilon$$

But that's all I did. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $$z-w^{2}=(x_0-y_0^{2})+(z-x_0)+(y_0^{2}-w^{2})$$ $$ >(x_0-y_0^{2})-|z-x_0|-|w-y_0||w+y_0|$$ $$\geq (x_0-y_0^{2})-|z-x_0|-|w-y_0|(2y_0-|w-y_0|)$$ $$>(x_0-y_0^{2})-\epsilon -\epsilon (2y_0-\epsilon)$$ (Note that $y_0 >0$).

Comment: We say $y_{0}>0$ because $y>x^2$. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. @beingmathematician

Answer (score 2):

**An alternative, quick way:**

Let $f(x,y) = y-x^2$. Then, your set becomes:

\begin{align*}
S=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R:y>x^2\}&=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R:y-x^2>0\} \\
&=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R:f^{-1}((0,\infty))\}.
\end{align*}

The set $\left(0,\infty\right)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$ and since $f$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}\left(\left(0,\infty\right)\right)$ is also open.

This concludes the proof.

Comment: I just did this way. But thanks !

Comment: @beingmathematician Didn't know, but glad to share an alternative thought! Kavi Rama Murthy provided the answer you're probably looking for in a nicely hint-way.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy This is why I wrote alternative and prompted him to your answer :) Good morning!